# Compiling RealTek RTL81111E driver r8168 on linux 2.6.24

Tags: linux

I am running old linux software (kubuntu 8.04) on a number of systems and have to keep the main software for a while. It works fine on old systems, but now I have to install it on a new system, with new hardware.

I ran into problems with the network. The old system was Realtek RTL8111CP and now it is RTL81111E. The driver is r8169. I am trying to install an appropriate driver and hope that r8168-8.045.08 will work.

I am trying to compile it. I installed the packages build-essential and linux-header-generics, which I think are required.

When building I get lots of errors. Just as an example:

```
/home/donken/r8168-8.045.08/src/r8168.h:69: error: ‘struct dev_pm_info’ has no member named ‘runtime_status’
```

I suppose there is a PATH missing or some packages. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like that struct is not available in kernels <2.6.32. If it is not an option to update the kernel maybe you can get an archived version of the module source. I found this tutorial, which might be helpful https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Comment: Thanks DrHopfen. I am now trying to install an older version of the driver (r1000_v1.07). Is that what you meant? Still no success. Compilation errors! Sorry, your link didn't help me. But thanks!